# Javascript regex - Match domain and any possible sub-domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match flickr.net and its subdomains:

> https://blog.flickr.net/en/2006/01/11/cool-stuff-happening-all-over/
>   https://www.flickr.net/en/2006/01/11/cool-stuff-happening-all-over/
>   https://flickr.net/en/2006/01/11/cool-stuff-happening-all-over/

So this cannot match

> http://www.random.com/en/flickr.net/

I've tried this pattern without success:

```
/https?:\/\/\S.flickr.net/
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm trying to match flickr.net and possible subdomains. The example I provided has "flickr.net" in its path

Comment: Your regex will only match subdomains with exactly a single non-whitespace character before the first dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/https?:\/\/(\S*\.)?flickr\.net/
```

If you want [this](https://regex101.com/r/tB8sH5/2).

Comment: Fails to prevent `http://www.random.com/en/https://flickr.net/`: needs an anchor to the beginning of the string.